# Как реализовать вывод видеофайла с сервера на сайт в Flask?

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, flask

Имеется сервер и видео на нем. Бэкенд представлен библиотекой Flask на Python. Сейчас видео доступно по заданному адресу, при обращении к которому выполняется функция:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return send_from_directory(os.getcwd() + f'/movie/', 'video1.webm')
```

Всё работает отлично, но как только страницу открывают больше 1 человека одновременно, то происходит долгое ожидание загрузки видео с сервера - 10 и более секунд. Какой подход в этом случае лучше, чтобы видео могло одновременно смотреть, например 3000 человек, используя только сервер, как видеохостинг?

Comment: Прекратить раздавать файлы через Flask (и через Python вообще) и взять оптимизированный для этих задач nginx.

Comment: Я указал кусочек кода. Приложение большое и основано на Flask, поэтому передавать нужно с использованием Flask

Comment: Перед любым приложением на Flask обязан стоять nginx. Если у вас не стоит — вы делаете плохо и не разбираетесь в администрировании и безопасности. Берите nginx.

Comment: Чтобы 3000 человек могли одновременно работать с Flask-приложением, вам требуется запустить ваше Flask-приложение в 3000 потоках/процессах.